# how can i count selected multi pick list values in report?

Tags: reporting, multi-select

I have a few multipicklist field in my contact and i would like to report on how many values selected for these fields per contact in report. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a number field with 0 decimal places named Count_Of_Selections__c
2. Create a text field named anything you want
3. Create a WFR that copies the value of the MSPL to the text field in #2
4. Create a WFR to populate that field with the count of items

`LEN( Name)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Name,";",""))/LEN(";")+1`

replacing NAME with your field from #2

3. Use the field in #1 in your report

or you can follow the instructions here:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000221353&language=en_US

> But you have to updated the formula each time you add valued to the
>   picklist and the compile size might be too big if you have a lot of
>   values
>
> Navigate to the fields area of the appropriate object.
>
> 1. For standard objects, from Setup, click Customize, select the appropriate object, and click Fields.
> 2. For custom objects, from Setup, click Create | Objects, and select one of the custom objects in the list.
> 3. In Custom Fields & Relationships, click New.
> 4. Choose the Formula as the type and click Next
> 5. Enter a field label(Salesforce populates Field Name using the field label)
> 6. Select the Formula Return Type as Number
> 7. Choose the number of decimal places as 0
> 8. Select the Advanced Formula
> 9. To insert a function, double-click its name in the list, or select it and click Insert Selected Function
>
>    ```
>              IF(INCLUDES( Multi_Picklist_Field__c , "Value A"),1,0) +
>              IF(INCLUDES( Multi_Picklist_Field__c , "Value B"),1,0) +
>              IF(INCLUDES( Multi_Picklist_Field__c , "Value C"),1,0) +
>              IF(INCLUDES(  Multi_Picklist_Field__c , "Value D"),1,0)
>    ```
> 10. To check your formula for errors, click Check Syntax and Save.

Basically there is no *clean* way to do it declaratively. A trigger could populate it much easier

```
trigger countItems on Account(before insert, before update){

     for(Account a : trigger.new){
          if(string.isblank(a.PICKLISTFIELD__c)) continue;
          a.MYCOUNTFIELD__c = a.PICKLISTFIELD__c.split(';').size();

     }

}
```

Comment: Multi-select picklist fields can only be used in these functions:
INCLUDES
ISBLANK
ISNULL
ISCHANGED
PRIORVALUE

Comment: @Oleksiy - Thanks for pointing that out. Updated answer.